# how to not escape space and backslashes in echo and while in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line-arguments

I'm passing two positional args to a script to run, both args are a path, and while in the scenario analyzing the paths, the problem is sometimes there is some path like:  `m i sc .       . .  . ..  . .` it has dots and spaces, and sometimes even we have a backslash in dir names.

It is so tried to get arguments via two procedures, directly and via `at sign`.

```
SOURCE_ARG=$1
DESTINATION_ARG=$2
```

and

```
ARG_COUNT=0
for POSITIONAL_ARGUMENTS in "${@}"
do
    ((ARG_COUNT++))
    ARGUMENT_ARRAY[$ARG_COUNT]=$POSITIONAL_ARGUMENTS
done
```

In the loop, I iterate through the result of commands that have  forwarded to them.

```
while IFS= read -r dir
do
    echo "${ARGUMENT_ARRAY[1]}"
    echo "${dir}"
    while IFS= read -r item
    do

       # do some stuff

    done < <(ls -A "$dir"/)
done < <(du -hP "$SOURCE_ARG" | awk '{$1=""; print $0}' | grep -v "^.$" | sed "s/^ //g")
```

when i use `echo "${ARGUMENT_ARRAY[1]}"` i get the same path as i need to check but when using loop iteration varible as dir in here ->`echo "${dir}"` i got all the spaces escaped, since other commands for that path could not do their jobs.

What I'm Asking for is that how can I get the output of `$dir` within the loop and as like as `echo "${ARGUMENT_ARRAY[1]}"` that i mentioned above(input with all spaces and backslashes)

Comment: For starters, you can replace the entire `for` loop with `ARGUMENT_ARRAY=("$@")`, if that array is even necessary in place of `"$@"` itself. Second, [don't parse `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Beyond that, it's not clear what you are asking.

Comment: Don't use all-uppercase variable names. These are conventionally reserved for environment varables.

Comment: I don't see anything here that will automatically escape strings. `echo` doesn't do it. `ls` will escape names when used with the `--escape` option or it's writing to a terminal, but it's writing to a pipe here.

Comment: @chepner thanks for suggestions, I added sth at the end of the Question!
If it isn't apparent yet, let me know to make it more clear.

Comment: The only reason why `$dir` would have escape in it is because `du` is printing the filenames with escapes. But AFAIK it doesn't do that.

Comment: If a filename has more than one space in a row, your use of `awk` will collapse them into a single space.

Comment: Why are you using `du` if you're not interested in the usage column? If you just want a list of directories, use `find "$SOURCE_ARG" -type d`

Comment: @Barmar, thanks for your suggestion. Let us say we run the script like this, `./script.sh "this is a dir . e. c . t . o   r y\i" `"destination" and as you see, there some spaces and backslash in it. Also, there is another problem two. We have the same kind of namings for file in those paths too!

Comment: Can you add the erroneous output to the question?

Comment: Try `printf "%s\n" "$dir"` instead of `echo`, as some versions of `echo` process escape sequences.

Comment: But it should process them the same from `$dir` as `${ARGUMENT_ARRAY[1]}`

Comment: I haven't been able to reproduce the problem. I created a directory like that, and ran your script, the output looked fine.

Comment: Why did you post on [unix.se] instead of [so]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Barmar in comments.

> The only reason that filenames are without escapes (i.e. you see directories with no special character or special characters have been escaped) is because `du` is printing the filenames with escapes, so `$dir` variable would have escaped once and special characters are no longer available for the other loop iteration in my problem.

Now that we know the problem was raised by using `du` in my script:

```sh
while IFS= read -r dir

        # do sth

done < <(du -hP "$SOURCE_ARG" | awk '{$1=""; print $0}' | grep -v "^.$" | sed "s/^ //g")
```

We can change the `du` to `find` and the problem is solved:

```sh
while IFS= read -r dir

        # do sth

done < <(find "$SOURCE_ARG" -type d –)
```

**PS 1:**

Another problem raised as I wanted to print the lines to check them if they are ok or not (i.e. while debugging application) was with `echo`.

So be sure to try `printf "%s\n" "$dir"` instead of `echo`, as some versions of `echo` process escape sequences.

```sh
    echo "${dir}"

    printf "%s\n" "$dir"
```

**PS 2:**

Also If a filename has `more than one space in a row`, The way I used `awk`, was collapsing them into a single space.

```sh
awk '{$1=""; print $0}' | grep -v "^.$" | sed "s/^ //g"
```